# mysql max value plus associated value

Tags: mysql

This correctly returns the max date value.

```
SELECT MAX(DateEnd) FROM Balances WHERE SourceId = " & hResultSource!id
```

I would like to also recover a another value (BalEnd) from the same record

```
SELECT MAX(DateEnd), BalEnd FROM Balances WHERE SourceId = " & hResultSource!id & " GROUP BY BalEnd"
```

This returns a strange value for BalEnd

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have a look at the second answer (the one with more votes). This answers your question. It is a duplicate, although the question title and accepted answer can be misleading.

Comment: `GROUP BY BalEnd` means you get a separate row for each different value of `BalEnd`.

Comment: Thank you, the MySQL documention provided the answer